# Why my streamBuilder return an empty list from firestore

Tags: android, flutter, list, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hi everyone im new in flutter i try to get a list of custom model from firestore but it returns me an empty list whereas i have one document in my collection
here is my streamTransformer

```
static StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<T>>
  transformer<T>(T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson) =>
      StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>,
          List<T>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (QuerySnapshot data, EventSink<List<T>> sink) {
          final snaps = data.docs
              .map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)
              .toList();
          final residences = snaps.map((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();

          sink.add(residences);
        },
      );
```

here is the stream:

```
  static Stream<List<ResidenceModel>> getResidences() {
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('residences')
    .orderBy(ResidencesField.updatedAt, descending: true)
    .snapshots()
    .transform(Utils.transformer(ResidenceModel.fromJson));
```

}

and here is where i try to get it but i get an empty list:

```
return StreamBuilder<List<ResidenceModel>>(
    stream: ResidenceModel.getResidences(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ResidenceModel>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive() ,
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.hasError) {
        const Center(
          child: Text(
              'Something get wrong') ,
        );
      }
      final residences = snapshot.data! ;
      print(residences) //<---------- output:[];
      return TabBarView(children: [
        Body(
          residencesList: residences,
          isMain: true,
        ),
```

i have no idea of where the problem coming from if someone can help please

Comment: You're creating a stream in your streambuilder: `stream: ResidenceModel.getResidences()` and that's broken. Don't build the stream as the stream: parameter in StreamBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the StreamBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

Comment: hi Randal SchWartz i tried this solution but nothing it still return an empty list i think that the problem is from the transformation